# How do i use read.fcs to read a file in R studio

Tags: r

I have a very trivial question, i am trying to access a file from a location i am able to open it and look at its attributes but when i use read function read.fcs i am not able to do it. 
the server code i am using is 
library(shiny)

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {


output$fcsfile <- renderPrint({
str(input$flowfile)
summary(input$flowfile)
print(input$flowfile)
read.FCS(input$flowfile)
 })

output$wbc <- renderPrint({input$num1})
)}
```

the ui.r code is

```
library(shiny)
library(flowCore)
library(flowViz)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("FLOW CYTOMERY TEST DEMO"),

fileInput("flowfile", label = h3("File input")),

 hr(),
 fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("fcsfile"))),
numericInput("num1", label = h6("WBC COUNT"), value = 1,min = 0, max = NA, 
step = NA),

 hr(),
 fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("wbc"))))
```

how do I access the file.

Comment: I am new so trying basic function, but i am not able to access it the error i am getting is 'filename' must be character skalar

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to follow [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flowCore/versions/1.38.2/topics/read.FCS) and ensure passing right parameters, specifically parameter *filename* should be a file path.

[Here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/24638/) you can see error handling for *'filename' must be character skalar*